# dbt (1.5.3) doesn't find snapshot specifications/configuration

Tags: dbt

Using CLI dbt and

```
Core:
  - installed: 1.5.3
  - latest:    1.5.3 - Up to date!

Plugins:
  - postgres: 1.5.3 - Up to date!
```

dbt seems unable to find snapshots. After inserting into a `raw_ppi` table from outside dbt, I materialize as stg_ppi with recasting of columns: `dbt run -s stage` and `dbt test -s stage` pass 100%. Snapshots, however, just falls over as if it isn't there:

```
$ dbt snapshot    
10:39:14 Running with dbt=1.5.3  
10:39:15  Registered adapter: postgres=1.5.3  
10:39:15  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.  
There are 4 unused configuration paths:
- models.dbt_ppi.raw
- models.dbt_ppi.unveil
- models.dbt_ppi.trans
- snapshots.dbt_ppi

10:39:15  Found 1 model, 74 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 662 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 2 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics, 0 groups  
10:39:15  
10:39:15  Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args
```

I haven't implemented the trans and unveil models yet, so no surprises that it flag those. So far I've got

```
models/
├── raw
│   └── raw_schema.yml
├── stage
│   ├── stg_ppi.sql
│   └── stg_schema.yml
├── trans
└── unveil
```

and

```
snapshots/
└── snapshot_ppi.sql
```

snapshot_ppi.sql is

```
{{% snapshot snapshot_ppi %}}

{{
    config(
        unique_key = 'unique_composite'
        , strategy = 'check'
        , check_cols = [
            field1
            , field2
            , ...
        ]
    )
}}

SELECT
    *
    , field1 || '-' || field2 as unique_composite
FROM {{ source('stage', 'stg_ppi') }}

{{% endsnapshot %}}
```

stage/stg_schema.yml includes

```
sources:
- name: stage
  schema: |
      {%- if  target.name == "dev" -%} dev_stage
      {%- elif target.name == "prod"  -%} prod_stage
      {%- else -%} invalid_
      {%- endif -%}
  tables:
  - name: stg_ppi
```

and dbt_project.yml is

```
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'dbt_ppi'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'dbt_ppi'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/
# directory as views. These settings can be overridden in the individual model
# files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  dbt_ppi:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    raw:
      +schema: 'raw'
      +materialized: 'table'
    stage:
      +schema: 'stage'
      +materialized: 'view'
    trans:
      +schema: 'trans'
      +materialized: 'table'
    unveil:
      +schema: 'unveil'
      +materialized: 'view'

snapshots:
  dbt_ppi:
    +target_schema: 'snapshots'
    +strategy: 'check'
    +updated_at: 'updated_at'
```

I have another project that I'm working on concurrently, and that works fine. The only  difference I think is that I started that one with a duplication of a different project, and is "out of date" version 1.5.2, whereas for this one I started from scratch with a `dbt init` and is up-to-date version 1.5.3. In a comparison between the two, I can't see any substantive difference with why the other should run snapshots just fine, where as this one doesn't seem to believe that they're there.

Admittedly, the more time I spend trying to understand the jaffleshop examples, the more confused I get, so I may have something unwittingly but obviously wrong. Can anybody spot anything wrong? Or does the newest micro-version update appear to have a bug?

Comment: Your snapshot code opening and closing blocks are not correct Jinja syntax. It should be single brackets like {% snapshot %}.

Comment: Thank you @AdamKipnis -- I stuffed that up because I generated the snapshot file using a python script, and should have used 3 brackets instead of 4. Many thanks!